# tidyverse rename_with giving error when trying to provide new names based on existing column values

Tags: r, tidyverse, rename

Assuming the following data set:

```
df <- data.frame(...1 = c(1, 2, 3),
                 ...2 = c(1, 2, 3),
                 n_column = c(1, 1, 2))
```

I now want to rename all vars that start with "...". My real data sets could have different numbers of "..." vars. The information about how many such vars I have is in the `n_column` column, more precisely, it is the maximum of that column.

So I tried:

```
df %>%
  rename_with(.cols = starts_with("..."),
              .fn   = paste0("new_name", 1:max(n_column)))
```

which gives an error:

```
# Error in paste0("new_name", 1:max(n_column)) : 
#   object 'n_column' not found
```

So I guess the problem is that the paste0 function does look for the column I provide within the current data set. Not sure, though, how I could do so. Any ideas?

I know I could bypass the whole thing by just creating an external scalar that contains the max. of n_column, but ideally I'd like to do everything in one pipeline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need information from `n_column`, `.cols` will pass only those columns that satisfy the condition (`starts_with("...")`).

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% rename_with(~paste0("new_name", seq_along(.)),  starts_with("..."))

#  new_name1 new_name2 n_column
#1         1         1        1
#2         2         2        1
#3         3         3        2
```

This is safer than using `max(n_column)` as well, for example if the data from `n_column` gets corrupted or the number of columns with `...` change this will still work.

---

A way to refer to column values in `rename_with` would be to use anonymous function so that you can use `.$n_column`.

```
df %>% 
     rename_with(function(x) paste0("new_name", 1:max(.$n_column)),
                 starts_with("..."))
```

I am assuming this is part of longer chain so you don't want to use `max(df$n_column)`.

Comment: OK, this bypases the problem and works. I still don't understand why I'm getting my inital error and how I, theoretically, could pass the information from an existing column.

Comment: You can use an anonymous function to refer to column names. See my updated answer @deschen

Answer (score 1):

A completly other approach would be

```
df %>% janitor::clean_names()
  x1 x2 n_column
1  1  1        1
2  2  2        1
3  3  3        2
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_c`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    rename_with(~str_c("new_name", seq_along(.)),  starts_with("..."))
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
i1 <- startsWith(names(df), "...")
names(df)[i1] <- sub("...", "new_name", names(df)[i1], fixed = TRUE)
df
  new_name1 new_name2 n_column
1         1         1        1
2         2         2        1
3         3         3        2
```

Comment: Thanks, but isn‘t this basically the same approach as suggested by Ronak Shah above?

Comment: @deschen there is change in `str_c`.  So it is different.  The behavior is different when there are NAs

Comment: @deschen updated with another one, in case you are so